# Read multiple excel sheets on specific column and right them in one csv file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have multiple sheets in one excel file like Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3,etc. Now I have to list all the particular column in one csv file. Both the sheets has one unique column "Attribute" and only those records should be listed in the csv file line by line. (First sheet's 'Attribute' values should be in 1st line and 2nd sheet's 'Attribute' values should be in 2nd line and etc.,)

If instances,

- Sheet1:

Attribute,Order

P,1

Emp_ID,2

DOJ,3

Name,4

- Sheet2:

Attribute,Order

C,1

Emp_ID,2

Exp,3

LWD,4

**Expected result:** (In some .csv file)

P,Emp_ID,DOJ,name

C,Emp_ID,Exp,LWD

Note: Line starting from P should be in first line and C should be in 2nd line and etc.,

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

excel = 'E:\Python Utility\Inbound.xlsx' 
K = 'E:\Python Utility\Headers_Files\All_Header.csv' 
df = pd.read_excel(excel,sheet_name = None) 
data = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Attribute']).T 
print data 
M = data.to_csv(K, encoding='utf-8',index=False,header=False) 
print 'done'
```

Output show's as below:

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: [Attribute] done

If I use `sheet_name = 'sheet1'` then DataFrame works good and data loaded as expected in csv file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your expectation some one here will create the script for you? If you are working on a script and encountered an error, specify it and we will try to help

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code so that it can be formatted using the "format as code" button, or by indenting it with four spaces.